Can I check if my polling place has Overseers of Election appointed for the next election day?
In the US, Overseers of Election (distinct from Poll Watchers) are two court appointed individuals for an election district that require a petition to the Court of Common Pleas with 5 signatures from eligible electors of said district.
Is there a way that one can check if the court has appointed overseers for a voting location?

FWTW Reddit 'folklore' says that despite the statute it's extremely uncommon to have those appointed https://www.reddit.com/r/Pennsylvania/comments/1en5sdb/how_can_i_check_if_my_polling_place_already_has/ It might have been some civil war era statute/practice.

Nowadays, it's common to refer to state officials [appointed by the executive] in charge of elections as "election overseers". Whether that's a coincidence, or the courts' role in the appointment process has gradually eroded (but the law is still on the books), I'm not sure. Certainly the courts are also referred to sometimes as "election overseers".

I don't know if the provision is ever used, but this election officer's handbook from earlier this year in Allegheny county specifically does mention overseers (page 51).  See also the PA Attorney General's FAQ (under "individuals allowed inside the polls).

If this is almost never exercised, there may not be an automated way to check. You might have to contact your city government or the state AG.
